Python unresolved reference with inner class
I'm learning inner classe in python, pycharm tips me

unresolved reference Clienta

in this code

model = Clienta.OverviewSchema.Overview

class Clienta(Document):
    class Overview(EmbeddedDocument):
        consume = IntField(required=True)
        purchaseToken = ListField(StringField(), )

    purchase_token = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    clientId = StringField(required=True)
    overview = EmbeddedDocumentField(Overview, )

    class OverviewSchema(ModelSchema):
        class Meta:
            model_skip_values = ()
            model = Clienta.Overview #unresolved reference Clienta
            # model = Overview #unresolved reference Overview 

class ClientaSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        # model_skip_values = ()
        model = Clienta

How to fix it? I know move the OverviewSchema to the outside will solve the problem, but I'm wondering why the OverviewSchema can't find the parent class and the parent's inner class(Overview).

Clienta simply is not defined yet; you are still evaluating the body of the class statement that will create the type and bind it to the name Clienta. Overview, on the other hand, should be defined, even if not yet available as Clienta.Overview.

Think about whether you really need nested classes like this. It tends to be an anti-pattern in Python, it often comes from people who are used to Java class nesting.
